# How can I change the language in Sins of a Solar Empire?

Tags: sins-of-a-solar-empire

I've been given an Italian copy of Sins of a Solar Empire on DVD. The cut scenes are in English, but all the menus are in Italian. I can't find an obvious menu option for changing the language. Is it possible to change it? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can either change the language file or install it through Impulse. Take a look on [this thread](http://forums.sinsofasolarempire.com/368883) on the official Sins' forum.